# Pycharm Code Completion does not work in methods or functions

Tags: python, pycharm

This is so weird...
Code completion only works outside a method...
Anyone know how to fix this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way it should work, and it has nothing to do with being inside or outside a method or function.

Your function does not have [type hints](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/) (type annotations generally speaking), so Pycharm's type checker can't infer the type of `text`, and it assigns the `Any` type to `texts`.

[image]

Instead, if you put a type hint like `text: str`, then `texts` will be treated like a `List[str]`:

[image]

and Pycharm's autocomplete will show its methods:

[image]